# C# WPF ListView Individualize each row's font size dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm trying to create a dynamic list in WPF using ListView. My code reads in a file and will import it into this list to be displayed. My intent is that every time a tab character is seen in the string, the row's font size will decrease by 4 (starting at a font size of 24). So all strings with no tabs will be at 24, all strings with 1 tab at 20, all strings at 2 tabs 16 and so on). I would ideally like to set the row styling every time I add a row to the list (at least, I think that would be the easiest).

So, ideally I would see something like this:

```
String(Font Size 24)

    String(Font Size 20)

      String(Font Size 16)

    String(Font Size 20)

      String(Font Size 16)

         And so on.....
```

I'm very new to WPF and am finding it very difficult to manipulate it using XAML at the moment. I can't seem to find the command to make each row individualized for style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to set up an `ItemTemplate` to house our styled control

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
   <DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Second, what is `FontSize` dependent on? The string itself. This means that we need to bind it in the item template:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Text}"/> //Could be "." if binding to List<String>
```

Note that we can do this because `FontSize` is a Dependency Property. Finally, the text is obviously not a number, so we need a **converter** to change it to one:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Path=Text,
                              Converter={StaticResource TabCountStringConverter}}"/> 

public class TabCountStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(...)
    {
         return (value as String).Count(c => c == '\t'); //Count tabs
    }

    public object ConvertBack(...)
    {
         return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

I make no claims for my tab counting function, but its a good start :) It needs an element to change the tab count into the correct font size, a `Dictionary` perhaps. The implementation is really up to you.

You could also set this on the row "container" control, as it should apply to the nested controls as well. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize(v=vs.110).aspx).

To try and clear up confusion from the comments:

1. "Path=." means "Bind to the object itself". Since you already *have* the string in question as the data context, you don't want to bind to a property of it, you want to bind to the string.
2. Static resources must be defined in the `Resources` collection of your container; for example:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <local:TabCountStringConverter x:Key="TabCountStringConverter"/>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   ```

   Where "local" was previously defined as an `xmlns`. The return value of the converter is used when evaluating the binding, what we are doing here is telling the framework *which converter to use*. If we don't make one (as seen above) you will get a resource not found exception.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback. I am a little confused on the use of converters. I have a List<string> specified with the string values I'm inserting into the display. Does the converter get called on every row?

Comment: @Scintir Yes. More specifically, the converter is called *every time the binding evaluates*, which of course, would happen for every row. It will also happen every time the backing field is changed (assuming `INotifyPropertyChanged` on that object would work, for a `List<String>` it would not).

Comment: I think I am starting to understand a little bit of the structure; however, I'm still having a little bit of a problem. I'm getting an error "Additional information: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception." when running the program. It appears to revolve around the new addition of the XAML code. 
I've added:
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Text}"/> 
<TextBlock FontSize="Binding Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TabCountStringConverter}" />
</TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

Comment: Heh, sorry. I'm still really confused by the syntax. I thought that might just have been some parameter setting. I also did a copy/paste error missing the DataTemplate.
The textblock I have now is: 
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource TabCountStringConverter}}" /> 
I don't understand how the Path=. works for a string.
As for the static resource, isn't that set on the return value? If so, I set it as:
'string TabCount = null;'
'TabCount = value.ToString().Count(ch => ch == '\t').ToString();'
'return TabCount;'
Thank you!

Comment: @Scintir See my edit. You also need to return a `double` not a string, since that is what `FontSize` expects.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realized where I was going wrong (declaring the resource). Everything is working exactly as I want it to. You rock